# Trying to set up flask with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have followed a simple guide, and trying to show my flask application, but it wont show. I am running everything through ssh on a ubuntu server.

Have my flask app and wsgi.py in /var/www/application/

My nginx config is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name application;
 
        access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/appliation.error.log;
 
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/application/application.sock;
        }
}
```

I have symlinked the file to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Then here is my gunicorn application config
located in: /etc/systemd/system/application.service

```
[Unit]
Description=application.service - A Flask application run with Gunicorn.
After=network.target
 
[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/application/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/application.sock wsgi:app
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Have checked all processes are running, and systemd status ok, but when i try to curl

```
http://application
```

I get nothing?

My app.py

```
from flask import Flask
 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>Nginx & Gunicorn</h1>"
```

wsgi.py

```
from main import app
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What am I missing here, how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/application.sock wsgi:app
```

the problem is the path **/var/www/application.sock**, it should be: **/var/www/application/application.sock**

You can still view the status of the service with the command:
`sudo systemctl status <service_name>`

To understand if the command specified in the service file is correct, or if the application has problems starting, try to start it directly from the command line:

```
cd /var/www/application/ && /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/application/application.sock wsgi:app
```

Comment: I have changed that, and it is runnig fine, with checking status, but how to I access the app? view it?

Comment: in the browser type http://<your_ip>/